# asynchronous context with useEffect in React

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, react-context, use-effect

im trying to create an api request with the header value, that is received from a context component. However, as soon as the page component is loaded, it throws an `Cannot read property '_id' of null` exception. Is there a way to run the useEffect function, as soon as the context is loaded?

**main component:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import "./overview.scss";

/* COMPONENTS */;
import axios from 'axios';
import { GlobalContext } from '../../components/context/global';

const Overview = () => {
  const [bookings, setBookings] = useState([]);
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  const [user, setUser] = useContext(GlobalContext);

  useEffect(() => {
      axios
      .get(`/api/v1/bookings/user/${user._id}`)
      .then(res => setBookings(res.data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
      .finally(() => setLoaded(true));
  }, [user]);
```

**context component:**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, createContext} from 'react';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

/* GLOBAL VARIABLES (CLIENT) */
export const GlobalContext = createContext();

export const GlobalProvider = props => {

    /* ENVIRONMENT API URL */
    const [user, setUser] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getSession = async () => {
            const user = await sessionStorage.getItem('authorization');
            setUser(jwt.decode(user));
    }
    getSession();
    }, [])

    return (
        <GlobalContext.Provider value={[user, setUser]}>
            {props.children}
        </GlobalContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue here is `useEffect` is running on mount, and you don't have a user yet. You just need to protect against this scenario

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!user) return;

  // use user._id
},[user])
```

Naturally, when the Context fetches the user it should force a re-render of your component, and naturally `useEffect` should re-run as the dependency has changed.

Answer (score 0):

put a condition before rendering you GlobalProvider, for example:

```
 return (
    {user.length&&<GlobalContext.Provider value={[user, setUser]}>
        {props.children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>}
);
```

If user is not an array just use this

```
 return (
    {user&&<GlobalContext.Provider value={[user, setUser]}>
        {props.children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>}
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately it throws me an `Cannot read property length of null`. I suppose that the async function has been not loaded, yet.

Comment: Why `user.length`? Doesn't look like `user` would be an array here

Comment: const [user, setUser] = useState([]); ?

Comment: @FrançoisRichard ah I see, the default value for the state is misleading as it doesn't get used as an array (nor would the use of language suggest it, all singular). Also, FWIW, you wouldn't want to make `user` a dependency of `useEffect` in the context otherwise you would end up with a continuous loop of fetching user data.

Comment: yeah true about the loop